# How to exchange code for token for importing gmail address book

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I am getting problem as I got the code and now I want access token in exchange of code but as pure google documentation to exchange code for token u need to send parameters

- code  The authorization code returned from the initial request
- client_id     The client_id obtained during application registration
- client_secret     The client secret obtained during application registration
- redirect_uri  The URI registered with the application
- grant_type    As defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification, this field must contain a value of authorization_code and by

  ```
  var parameters = new OAuth2Parameters {
      code =
      ClientId = "",
      ClientSecret = "",
      RedirectUri = "",
      Scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
      grant_type =,
  };
  OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
  ```

I am forming parameters but OAuth2Parameters doesn't contain definition for grant type and google send bad server request error. Can anyone please help me with the code to exchange code for access token and how to exchange that?
This is the link in which it is said that in which form google url have to be made
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl
so kindly help me and if i pass to url withour grant type parameter then it sends error saying

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the link you posted it gives you the answer:

> grant_type    As defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification, this field must
>   contain a value of **authorization_code**.

Set the value to the literal string "authorization_code"

```
grant_type = "authorization_code",
```